# How do i get rid of white space around image and table cells in HTML email

Tags: html, css

I have a pre-designed HTML email that i have sliced and coded using Komodo edit. All content is within a table where `display: block` and `border-collapse: collapse;` have been added to the tables inline-CSS and also `line-height: 0px;` to the cells inline-CSS. I have been using EmailonAcid to test my HTML email and what seems to be happening is everything looks fine on every email program except for Outlook. Outlook is addining extra white space to the sliced images causing the surrounding content/images to become out of line.

```
<table id="Table_01" style="border: 1px solid #D6D6D7; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-collapse: collapse;" width="800" height="1501" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_01.jpg" width="800" height="312" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="width: 800; height:199px; padding: 20px 10px 0px 15px;">
    <p> ALL MY TEXT GOES HERE</p>
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_03.jpg" width="800" height="37" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_04.jpg" width="180" height="47" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 135px; height: 47; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase;">
    Text here
            <br/>
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">&#163;#XX.XX#</span>
            </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_06.jpg" width="485" height="47" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_07.jpg" width="800" height="88" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 228px; height: 21px; font-size: 12px; text-transform: uppercase; ">

                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;

           text here
            </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_09.jpg" width="572" height="21" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="width:" 90px;  height: 21px; font-size: 12px;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                &#163;#XX.XX#</span>    </td>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_11.jpg" width="710" height="21" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_12.jpg" width="800" height="140" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_13.jpg" width="605" height="48" alt=""></td>
    <td style="width: 195px; height: 48px; font-size: 12px;text-transform: uppercase;">
    text here
            <br/>
            <span style="font-weight: bold; ">&#163;#XX.XX#</span>
            </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_15.jpg" width="800" height="66" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="width: 800px; height: 145px; font-size: 24px; text-align: center;">
    #dealername#
            <br/>
            #contact_number#</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_17.jpg" width="800" height="329" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/edm_personalised_02_18.jpg" width="800" height="58" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="90" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="90" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="48" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="87" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="290" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img style="display: block;" src="images/spacer.gif" width="195" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

Is there anyway of getting rid of the extra spaces?

Comment: Have you sliced the full layout into photshop/firworks and then exported it to HTML?

Comment: yes, i have sliced the full layout into photoshop and then saved the images as 'save for web and devices'.

Comment: The problem is that slicing full layout creates unnecessary white space for images, as that full layout slicing does not properly justify the `trs` and `tds` for the layout. I suggest you need to create a table in dreamweaver and slice only the images that you require and put them. This will solve your issue. I have done it practically and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try style="line-height: 0px;" on table cells.

Also look carefully if widths and heights on table cells and images are correct and set properly.

Comment: hiya i added this and it seemed to have no affect

Comment: I added a border and tested it to narrow down what is happening and it seems that Outlook is adding exta white space on one side of the image causing the surrounding images to be out of line. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Failing that, MailChimp has some very good pointers on building e-mail templates. I bet you will find a solution to your problem there. http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html

Comment: So after several re-slicing and fiddling with HTML code, basically Outlook doesn't like loads and loads of tiny sliced photoshop images especially when placed into a table as all the cells will be of different sizes. What i did was re-sliced the images ensuring that columns and rows had similar widths.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that slicing full layout sometimes creates unnecessary white space for images, as that full layout slicing does not properly justify the `trs` and `tds` for the layout. I suggest you need to create a table in dreamweaver and slice only the images that you require and put them manually. This will solve your issue. I have done it practically and it works for me.

Comment: i have also added cellspacing, cellpadding, border and width

Comment: So i've tried slicing only the images that i needed and i've tested my HTML email on email on acid and everything seems to look okay except for on outlook 07-13 where all the images are scattered, outlook.com IE 9(win) and outlook.com Safari 5 (win) seems to show a missing row.

Comment: Are you getting the white spaces now? - @iNeed_anAnswer

Comment: please find my response above

Comment: Post your Code. - @iNeed_anAnswer

Comment: i have added the modified above

Comment: It is not modified. It is the same as you had previously. - @iNeed_anAnswer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36780/discussion-between-ineed-ananswer-and-nathan-lee)